# Novel where a girl cares for psychic children, maybe set on a starship

Tags: story-identification, novel

I can't recall the name of a novel where a young human woman takes care of a group of children who may have psychic powers but the government does not know what their abilities are or when they will manifest. When the woman identifies that a child has an ability she notifies the authorities who take the child away, most like to be dissected for experimentation.

After the first child with an ability is taken away the young woman decides to protect the rest of the children. Most of the children display abilities. The book may be set on a starship due to some of the references.

When the young women goes out to socialize she wears a dress of twigs and leaves as she does not have a full body tattoo which is the current vogue.

There was an alien, a green being that may have been like a pet. The book itself had a green cover, and may have the word "green" in the title.

Comment: Hi there! Roughly when  did you read this? Also, you mentioned "references" to a starship - are those general memories or do you remember something more specific than that? Could you [edit] them in?

Comment: General references, and specifically that the society was closed off or indoors. It also referenced using 'tubes' to get around the place. From what I can remember it has the feel of people living in a generation ship. Due to this being read in the early 90s my memory isn't so clear on this part

Comment: @user14111 hmmmm... That may be my fault. Original title did read "novel green alien girl" but it may have been a missing comma rather than an adjective (what I thought). Indeed though, let's wait for OP to have the last call.

Comment: @user141111 It should have referred to the "green alien" - my bad for lack of clarity in the title originally. I've taken it out.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Perhaps [*Green Is for Galanx*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?848001), a 1980 novel by [Josephine Rector Stone](http://www.sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/stone_josephine_rector). The [cover](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51TEQZj-tSL.jpg) has quite a bit of green in it.

[image: Green Is for Galanx]

Excerpt from a review by [Baird Searles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baird_Searles) in [*Isaac Asimov's Science Fiction Magazine*, October 1980](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?59266+c), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Asimovs_v04n10_1980-10#page/n16/mode/1up):

> Willy's World is a self-contained, artificial satellite that has been
> wandering around the universe for several generations (shades of
> *Space: 1999* and *Lost in Space*!). It is a despotism that's not all that
> benevolent, and a group of mutant children with psi powers and
> their guardian, Ilona, fear that the children will be killed in order
> to analyze their talents for adaptation to android mentalities. When
> the chance comes, the group, accompanied by the shape-changing
> Galanx which they've more or less adopted as a pet, escapes to a
> new planet. There they must cope with the strangeness of a natural
> world, and escape the inevitable pursuit.

Comment: Thank you very much for finding this book!